# Not able to send data via UDP

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am not able to send UDP data to a system using IP address from my code.

We make a connection through the constructor and than send the messages in the code below.

This is my header File.

```
class UDPConnect
 {
  private:
   bool connected;
   SOCKET s;
   struct sockaddr_in server, si_other;
   int slen, recv_len;

   public:
        UDPConnect(const int iPort );   
        UDPConnect(const int iPort , const char* strHostName);
        int ReadIncomingPacket(byte *buffer, unsigned int buf_size);    
        int SendPacket(byte* buffer, unsigned int buf_size , const char* 
        strHostName);
        ~UDPConnect();
    };
```

This is the function defination.

```
 UDPConnect::UDPConnect(const int iPORT , const char* strHostName)
  {
    this->connected = false;
    this->s;
    WSADATA wsa;

    //Initialise winsock
   std::cout << ("\nInitialising Winsock...") << std::endl;
   if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsa) != 0)
    {
     std::cout << ("Failed. Error Code : %d", WSAGetLastError()) << 
     std::endl;
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

  //Create a socket
  if ((this->s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) == INVALID_SOCKET)
  {
     std::cout << ("Could not create socket : %d", WSAGetLastError());
  }

 std::cout << ("Socket created.\n");

//Prepare the sockaddr_in structure
this->server.sin_family = AF_INET;
this->server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr( strHostName );
this->server.sin_port = htons(iPORT);


//Bind
//if (::bind(this->s, (struct sockaddr *)&this->server, sizeof(this->server)) 
 == SOCKET_ERROR)
if (::bind(this->s, (struct sockaddr *)&this->server, 0) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    printf("Bind failed with error code : %d", WSAGetLastError());
    //exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
puts("Bind done");

this->connected = true;

}
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
int UDPConnect::SendPacket(byte *buffer, unsigned int buf_size , const char* 
 strHostName)
 {

   this->server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr( strHostName );
  if ((this->recv_len = sendto(this->s, (char*)buffer, buf_size + 1, 0, 
  (struct sockaddr *) &this->si_other, slen)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
   {
     std::cout << ("No Outgoing packet : %d", WSAGetLastError());
     //return -1;
   }

return recv_len;
```

}

Comment: Your code has a lot of error handling. Do you see any of the error messages? Does your program crash? How do you know the send fails? Need more information, not just a code dump.

Comment: No errors at all , I tried using boost Library also and i was able to send data through Boost Library.

Comment: Everything works fine but the host machine does not receive any data.

Comment: Have you tried downloading [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) to see "what's on the wire"?  Probably nothing, but it never hurts to check.  Also, what is the return value when you call `UDPConnect::SendPacket()`?

Comment: Where do you set `slen`?

Comment: The return value is 0.

Comment: I don't really know what I'm talking about but why are you passing `si_other` to `sendto`?

Comment: That is the (struct sockaddr *) recquired by the sendto function.

Comment: i had given the server value , but i think during troubleshooting it got changed to si_other.It did not work with the server value.

Comment: @shomet My reading of the documentation says that parameter is optional. Either you specify the server address with bind or with that parameter, you seem to be doing both. Just saying as I really don't know.

Comment: The best approach would be to cut out all the extraneous stuff. Just write a simple one function program that sends one packet. If that works then apply the lessons learned to your real program. If it doesn't then post that short program here. It's what we call a minimal, complete, verifiable program. It's much easier to help when you have that, instead of a portion of a larger program.

Comment: I think the problem is with this line server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.127.48");

Comment: I get Bind failed error.

Comment: What error code?

Comment: 10049 is the error code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see a number of mistakes in your code.

- Naming parameters `strHostName` when they can't actually accept hostnames, only IP addresses, is misleading. You should rename them, or else implement hostname resolution.
- mixing `printf`-style specifiers with `std::cout`.
- Calling `bind()` with an invalid `namelen` value. You had it right the first time, but you commented it out.
- incrementing `buf_size` when sending a packet. UDP operates on raw bytes, and raw data is not null terminated, only C-style strings are. If the caller wants to send a null terminated string, it should include the null terminator in the `buf_size` value it passes in.
- Calling `sendto()` with the wrong `sockaddr_in`, and an indeterminate `slen` value. Also, not providing any way to specify the target port to send to.

Try something more like this:

```
class UDPConnect
{
private:
    SOCKET s;
public:
    UDPConnect(ushort local_port, const char *local_addr = NULL);
    ~UDPConnect();
    int ReadIncomingPacket(byte *buffer, unsigned int buf_size);
    int SendPacket(byte* buffer, unsigned int buf_size, const char* remote_addr, ushort remote_port);
};

UDPConnect::UDPConnect(ushort local_port, const char* local_addr)
    : s(INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    WSADATA wsa;
    int err;

    //Initialise winsock
    std::cout << "\nInitialising Winsock..." << std::endl;
    err = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsa);
    if (err != 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed. Error Code : " << err << std::endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    //Create a socket
    if ((s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        err = WSAGetLastError();
        std::cout << "Could not create socket : " << err << std::endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    std::cout << "Socket created." << std::endl;

    //Prepare the sockaddr_in structure
    struct sockaddr_in server = {};
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(local_port);
    if (local_addr)
    {
        server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(local_addr);
        if (server.sin_addr.s_addr == INADDR_NONE)
        {
            std::cout << "Invalid local address specified" << std::endl;
            closesocket(s);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
    else
        server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    //Bind
    if (::bind(s, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        err = WSAGetLastError();
        std::cout << "Bind failed with error code : " << err << std::endl;
        closesocket(s);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    std::cout << "Bind done";
}

UDPConnect::~UDPConnect()
{
    closesocket(s);
}

int UDPConnect::ReadIncomingPacket(byte *buffer, unsigned int buf_size)
{
    int recv_len;
    if ((recv_len = recvfrom(s, (char*)buffer, buf_size, 0, NULL, NULL)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        int err = WSAGetLastError();
        std::cout << "No Incoming packet : " << err;
        //return -1;
    }
    return recv_len;
}

int UDPConnect::SendPacket(byte *buffer, unsigned int buf_size, const char* remote_addr, ushort remote_port)
{
    struct sockaddr_in si_other = {};
    int send_len;

    //Prepare the sockaddr_in structure
    si_other.sin_family = AF_INET;
    si_other.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(remote_addr);
    si_other.sin_port = htons(remote_port);

    if ((send_len = sendto(s, (char*)buffer, buf_size, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &si_other, sizeof(si_other))) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        int err = WSAGetLastError();
        std::cout << "No Outgoing packet : " << err;
        //return -1;
    }
    return send_len;
}
```